# field added dynamically to a ModelForm at __init__ does not save

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using Django profiles and was inspired by James Bennett to create a dynamic form (http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/ )

What I need is a company field that only shows up on my user profile form when the user_type is 'pro'.
Basically my model and form look like:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user_type = models.CharField(...
    company_name = models.CharField(...

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('company_name',)
```

And I add the company_name field in **init** like James Bennett showed:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    if (self.instance.pk is None) or (self.instance.user_type == 'pro'):
        self.fields['company_name'] = forms.CharField(...
```

The problem is that, when I try to save() an instance of UserProfileForm, the field 'company_name' is not saved...

I have gone around this by calling the field explicitly in the save() method:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    upf = super(UserProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)
    if 'company_name' in self.fields:
        upf.company_name = self.cleaned_data['company_name']
    if commit:
        upf.save()
    return upf
```

But I am not happy with this solution (what if there was more fields ? what with Django's beauty ? etc.). It kept me up at night trying to make the modelform aware of the new company_name field at **init** .

And that's the story of how I ended up on stackoverflow posting this...

Answer (score 3):

I would remove this logic from form and move it to factory. If your logic is in factory, you can have two forms:

- UserProfileForm
- ProUserProfileForm

ProUserProfileForm inherits from UserProfileForm and changes only "exclude" constant.

You will have then following factory:

```
def user_profile_form_factory(*args, instance=None, **kwargs):
   if (self.instance.pk is None) or (self.instance.user_type == 'pro'):
       cls = ProUserProfileForm
   else:
       cls = UserProfileForm
   return cls(*args, instance, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. Yes that works ! It's just that James Bennett called it "pretty ugly" in his post... so I was trying better with init :-)

Comment: Hi called "pretty ugly" creating class "on the fly". IMO this solution is fine by all standards.

Comment: I agree. It's the most direct and testable solution. No one can be confused by this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I found a solution:

```python
def AccountFormCreator(p_fields):
  class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = p_fields 
      widgets = {
        'photo': ImageWidget()
      }
  return AccountForm    
#...
AccountForm = AccountFormCreator( ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'photo', 'region') )
if request.POST.get('acforms', False):
  acform = AccountForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.u)
  if acform.is_valid():
    u = acform.save()
    u.save()
    ac_saved = True
else:
  acform = AccountForm(instance = request.u)
```

Answer (score 1):

When are you expecting the `user_type` property to be set? This seems like something that should be handled by javascript rather than trying to do funny things with the model form.

If you want the `company_name` field to appear on the client after they've designated themselves as a `pro`, then you can 'unhide' the field using javascript.

If instead, they've already been designated a `pro` user, then use another form that includes the `company_name` field. You can sub-class the original model form in the following manner.

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('company_name',)

class UserProfileProForm(UserProfileForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = None # or maybe tuple() you should test it
```

Then in your view, you can decide which form to render:

```
def display_profile_view(request):
    if user.get_profile().user_type == 'Pro':
        display_form = UserProfileProForm()
    else:
        display_form = UserProfileForm()
    return render_to_response('profile.html', {'form':display_form}, request_context=...)
```

This would be the preferred way to do it in my opinion. It doesn't rely on anything fancy. There is very little code duplication. It is clear, and expected.

Edit: **(The below proposed solution does NOT work)**

You could try changing the `exclude` of the meta class, and hope that it uses the instances version of exclude when trying to determine whether to include the field or not. Given an instance of a form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.instance.user_type == 'pro':
        self._meta.exclude = None
```

Not sure if that will work or not. I believe that the `_meta` field is what is used after instantiation, but I haven't verified this. If it doesn't work, try reversing the situation.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.instance.user_type != 'pro':
        self._meta.exclude = ('company_name',)
```

And remove the exclude fields altogether in the model form declaration. The reason I mention this alternative, is because it looks like the meta class (python sense of Meta Class) will exclude the field even before the `__init__` function is called. But if you declare the field to be excluded afterwards, it will exist but not be rendered.. maybe. I'm not 100% with my python Meta Class knowledge. Best of luck.

Comment: Yes I'm using js to do it for the registration form. The mechanism I'm investigating now is for the profile edit in "my account" section... and the reason why I don't want to do it in the view is because I'm using Django profiles... and this would force me to patch it.

Comment: @sam ahhh to be fair I don't know how that piece of software works, but from what I can guess, you're required to supply it with a form?

Comment: yes you tell him what profile form you are using and it applies its logic to it.

Comment: Not sure how to do exactly what you proposed because if I call these lines before my super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__  then the _meta doesn't exist. But if I call them after it's too late... I did something in the same idea : del self.fields['company_name'] and it works ! Not sure it is very beautiful though :-)

Comment: @sam, thanks for letting me know. If `_meta` doesn't exist before the call to `super()` then it's probably the case that modifying `instance.Meta.exclude` before `super()` would do the trick. I'll test this out myself later and update my answer.

Comment: @sam unfortunately, modifying the _meta or Meta inner class at run-time has no effect on the fields that are displayed. It *may* have an effect on what data is saved, but it will not stop those fields being available. Sorry to waste your time with this. If you are determined to dynamically modify these fields as you are, I think the `del self.fields['field']` option will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

What about removing **exclude = ('company_name',)** from Meta class? I'd think that it is the reason why *save()* doesn't save **company_name** field

Comment: Yes clearly and that would be ok for a pro user but then how do I exclude the company field in case the user is not a pro ? maybe do "del self.fields['company_name']" ?